# Haskell function which check whether a given value is in a tree

Tags: haskell

I m trying to create a function which check the whether a given value is in a tree, this what a got so far

```
data Tree = Null | 
     Node Int Tree Tree
     deriving (Show)

testTree = Node 20 (Node 3 (Node 12 Null Null) (Node 7 Null Null))
                  (Node 8 (Node 4 (Node 6 Null Null) Null) Null)

isMember :: Int->Tree -> Bool
isMember  x (Null)     = False
isMember  x(Node n st1 st2) = x == n
```

It didn't give me any error but I wanted to check the subtree as well

Answer (score 3):

You just need to call `isMember` recursively on each subtree, as needed.

```
isMember :: Int -> Tree -> Bool
isMember x Null = False
isMember x (Node n st1 st2) = x == n || isMember x st1 || isMember x st2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make `Tree` a polymorphic type and make it an instance of `Foldable`. With the [**`DeriveFoldable`** extension [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFoldable), then you can make use of [**`elem :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => a -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) to find out if the tree contains a given element:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a
  = Null 
  | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Foldable, Show)
```

Then your `isMember` is thus a special case of `elem`:

```
isMember :: Int -> Tree Int -> Bool
isMember = elem
```

For example:

```
Prelude> elem 5 testTree 
False
Prelude> elem 20 testTree 
True
Prelude> elem 4 testTree 
True
Prelude> elem 7 testTree 
True
Prelude> elem 9 testTree 
False
```